# Creating objects of class through its name stored in a string?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Can I create an object of a class at runtime, by extracting the class name stored in a string?

eg: I want to create and object of class `QButton` like

```
QString strClassName = "QButton";
QButton *pBtn = new strClassName();
```

I want to read an xml file of all the controls and instantiate them at runtime using this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the functionality provided by [`QUiLoader`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/quiloader.html)?